# trying to create a table that takes a user given image URL and displays it in the cell

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

hello I'm working on a simple project where a user inputs the information and it goes into a table. I want the user to have the ability to put in the URL for an image and have it show up when the cell is made in the table. I have a button that prompts the user to input a URL but I cant figure out how to put that into an image tag inside the created cell.

```js
let id = 0;

let img = document.getElementById("image").addEventListener("click", () => {
  function getUrl() {
    var url = prompt("Enter image URL");
    if (url) {
      return url;
    } else {
      return getUrl();
    }
  }
  image.src = getUrl();
});

document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", () => {
  let table = document.getElementById("list");
  let row = table.insertRow(1);
  row.setAttribute("id", `
test - $ {
  id
}
`);
  row.insertCell(0).innerHTML = document.getElementById("image").src = ""
  row.insertCell(1).innerHTML = document.getElementById("Game-name").value;
  row.insertCell(2).innerHTML = document.getElementById("hours-played").value;
  row.insertCell(3).innerHTML = document.getElementById("new-critic-score").value;
  row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = document.getElementById("new-personal-score").value;
  let actions = row.insertCell(5);
  actions.appendChild(createDeleteButton(id++));
  document.getElementById("Game-name").value = "";
  document.getElementById("hours-played").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new-critic-score").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new-personal-score").value = ""
});

function createDeleteButton(id) {
  let btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.className = "btn btn-primary";
  btn.id = id;
  btn.innerHTML = "Delete";
  btn.onclick = () => {
    console.log(`
Deleting row with id: test - $ {
  id
}
`);
    let elementToDelete = document.getElementById(`
test - $ {
  id
}
`);
    elementToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(elementToDelete);
  };
  return btn;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
</head>

<body class="container" style="background-color: rgb(3, 27, 63);">
  <!--Using HTML, Bootstrap, and JavaScript create a single page website that contains the following:
a. A Bootstrap styled table representing your choice of data.
b. A Bootstrap styled form that allows users to add input data as a new row to the table when submitted.
-->
  <br />
  <div class="card" style="background-color: rgb(7, 59, 75);color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div>
            <label for="new-critic-score">Critic score</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new-critic-score" placeholder="score out of 100" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div>
            <label for="new-personal-score">Personal score</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="new-personal-score" placeholder="score out of 100" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div>
            <label for="hours-played">Hours played</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="hours-played" placeholder="hours" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div>
            <label for="Game-name">Game name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Game-name" placeholder="Game title" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm">
        <div> <br>
          <button id="image" class="btn btn-secondary from-control">add image</button>
          <button id="add" class="btn btn-primary from-control">Create</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <table id="list" class="table table-dark table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>game image</th>
      <th>games played</th>
      <th>Hours played</th>
      <th>critic score</th>
      <th>personal score</th>
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

<img src="" alt="">
```

Comment: OK. There's quite a lot wrong with what you have. In order to set the src of an img element you need to call setAttribute on the element. You don't have a variable called image, so `image.src = getUrl();` isn't going to work. You are attempting to set the value of an image by it's id, but you are also attempting to create multiple rows. ids must be unique, so this approach will not work.

Comment: @LeeTaylor You're forgetting that `id="image"` creates a variable on window as `window.image`, so it's perfectly valid js (whether it's acceptable/ok or not is another matter) to do `image.src=url`.  Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/4bdsfm68/   The issue is likely, as you've stated, to do with duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't clear to me how you wanted to do it, I basically got the URL and stored it in a `var` to then make another variable that is the image `element` itself, using the stored URL.

```
let imgURL;
let imgElement;
document.getElementById("image").addEventListener("click", () => {
  imgURL = prompt("Enter image URL");
  imgElement = '<img src="' + imgURL + '" width="80px">';
});
```

I also did the deletion in a similar way. Creating the element with an `onclick` to a function that passes the element itself with `this` as a parameter.

```
let deleteButton = '<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)">'
```

and

```
row.insertCell(5).innerHTML = deleteButton;
```

Getting the ID by working your way up the parent elements to find the `rowIndex`.

```
function deleteRow(row) {
  var id = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("list").deleteRow(id);
}
```

Hope the code itself helps you understand it better.
https://jsfiddle.net/sahil_m03/jmk4rbp3/43/

Comment: Please include the relevant code *in the answer itself* - if there's a lot of code, then a fiddle link to a complete solution is ok, as long as there's the code that answers the question in the answer.